# How to build a keyword search with exact checkbox within a form on MS Access 2007?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have built a keyword search form on MS Access which works perfectly fine but only using LIKE so far, I am able to make it an exact keyword search no problem. What I actually want to do is add the option to switch to an exact or not.

We may want to show results that are only "Nottingham" or we may want to show results that include "nott".

*(The below two sets of code target different search functions so have different names)*

Here is the VBA code that I currently run for the LIKE search:

```
Private Sub btn_NameSearch_Click()
    Dim SQL As String

    SQL = "SELECT tbl_AllData.Customer_ID, tbl_Types.Types, tbl_Types.Type_ID, tbl_AllData.Name, tbl_AllData.[Town/City], tbl_AllData.Postcode, tbl_AllData.[Main Contact], tbl_AllData.Phone, tbl_AllData.Email, tbl_AllData.Website " _
        & "FROM tbl_Types INNER JOIN tbl_AllData ON tbl_Types.Type_ID = tbl_AllData.Type_ID " _
        & "WHERE [Name] LIKE '*" & Me.txt_NameSearch & "*'" _
        & "ORDER BY tbl_Types.Types, tbl_Alldata.Name; "

    Me.subAllDataList.Form.RecordSource = SQL
    Me.subAllDataList.Form.Requery

End Sub
```

Here is the VBA code that I am trying to implement that returns only #NAME?:

```
Private Sub btn_Town_CitySearch_Click()
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim SQLExact As String
    Dim SQLLike As String

    If chkbox_SearchExact = True Then
        SQLExact = "SELECT tbl_AllData.Customer_ID, tbl_Types.Types, tbl_Types.Type_ID, tbl_AllData.Name, tbl_AllData.[Town/City], tbl_AllData.Postcode, tbl_AllData.[Main Contact], tbl_AllData.Phone, tbl_AllData.Email, tbl_AllData.Website " _
        & "FROM tbl_Types INNER JOIN tbl_AllData ON tbl_Types.Type_ID = tbl_AllData.Type_ID " _
        & "WHERE [Town/City] = '*" & Me.txt_Town_CitySearch & "*'" _
        & "ORDER BY tbl_Types.Types, tbl_AllData.Name; "
        SQLExact = SQL
    Else
        SQLLike = "SELECT tbl_AllData.Customer_ID, tbl_Types.Types, tbl_Types.Type_ID, tbl_AllData.Name, tbl_AllData.[Town/City], tbl_AllData.Postcode, tbl_AllData.[Main Contact], tbl_AllData.Phone, tbl_AllData.Email, tbl_AllData.Website " _
        & "FROM tbl_Types INNER JOIN tbl_AllData ON tbl_Types.Type_ID = tbl_AllData.Type_ID " _
        & "WHERE [Town/City] LIKE '*" & Me.txt_Town_CitySearch & "*'" _
        & "ORDER BY tbl_Types.Types, tbl_AllData.Name; "
        SQLLike = SQL
    End If

    Me.subAllDataList.Form.RecordSource = SQL
    Me.subAllDataList.Form.Requery

End Sub
```

Let me know if there is anything further you need to see. I feel it is how I am setting the SQL string at the end of each IF statement result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since figured this out, it wasn't required that I reset each String I simply needed to set SQL as the result of either as below:

```
Private Sub btn_Town_CitySearch_Click()
    Dim SQL As String

    If chkbox_SearchExact = True Then
        SQL = "SELECT tbl_AllData.Customer_ID, tbl_Types.Types, tbl_Types.Type_ID, tbl_AllData.Name, tbl_AllData.[Town/City], tbl_AllData.Postcode, tbl_AllData.[Main Contact], tbl_AllData.Phone, tbl_AllData.Email, tbl_AllData.Website " _
        & "FROM tbl_Types INNER JOIN tbl_AllData ON tbl_Types.Type_ID = tbl_AllData.Type_ID " _
        & "WHERE [Town/City] = '" & Me.txt_Town_CitySearch & "'" _
        & "ORDER BY tbl_Types.Types, tbl_AllData.Name; "

    Else
        SQL = "SELECT tbl_AllData.Customer_ID, tbl_Types.Types, tbl_Types.Type_ID, tbl_AllData.Name, tbl_AllData.[Town/City], tbl_AllData.Postcode, tbl_AllData.[Main Contact], tbl_AllData.Phone, tbl_AllData.Email, tbl_AllData.Website " _
        & "FROM tbl_Types INNER JOIN tbl_AllData ON tbl_Types.Type_ID = tbl_AllData.Type_ID " _
        & "WHERE [Town/City] LIKE '*" & Me.txt_Town_CitySearch & "*'" _
        & "ORDER BY tbl_Types.Types, tbl_AllData.Name; "

    End If

    Me.subAllDataList.Form.RecordSource = SQL
    Me.subAllDataList.Form.Requery

End Sub
```